# Permission Denied on Docker Volumes on GCE

Tags: python, docker, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to run a Python Docker container on Google Compute Engine, with a docker Directory volume mounted at `/files` and hosted at `files`. I am running this code:

```
with open("/files/test.mp3") as mp3_file:
```

but I am getting a `Permission Denied [Errno 13]` error. How can I fix this?